# How O(2^n) is achieved in "permutation with space" problem?

Tags: string, optimization, big-o, permutation, backtracking

Basically the problem statement is: given a string, return all the possible permutations where spaces are added between the letters (or not)

Example:
Input: ABC;
Output: ABC, A BC, AB C, A B C;

I found it originally in geeksforgeeks and their solution was O(n*(2^n)). However i remember seeing somewhere a solution in O(2^n), where n is length of the original string.

```
list<string> getPermutations(string input, list<string>& permutations, int i = 1){
    if (permutations.empty() ==  true || input != permutations.back()){
        permutations.push_back(input);
    }
    if (i >= input.size()){
        return permutations;
    }
    getPermutations(input, permutations, i+1);
    input.insert(i, " ");
    getPermutations(input, permutations, i+2);
    return permutations;
}
```

This is the solution i wrote and acording to chat gpt the "input.insert" makes it O(n*(2^n)). Is this true? How could i make it O(2^n)?